# adding items with the same product id in the cart

Tags: laravel, session, laravel-5, cart, laravel-5.8

i am trying to add a second product with the same id but different size, but i keeps overwriting the first product.

when i dd the condition it display that it is in fact true but even if it has a different size it just takes the place of the first product.

```
    if(isset($cart[$id])&&($cart[$id]['size']==$request->productSize)) {
        $cart[$id]['quantity'] += $request->productQuantity;

        session()->put('cart', $cart);

        return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Product added to cart successfully!');
    ;}


    if(isset($cart[$id])&&($cart[$id]['size']!==$request->productSize)) {
        $cart = [ 
            $id => [
                "name" => $product->productName,
                "price" => $product->productPrice,
                "size" => $request->productSize,
                "quantity" => $request->productQuantity,
                "photo" => $product->productImage
            ]
            ];

        session()->put('cart', $cart);

        return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Product added to cart successfully!');
    ;}
```

expected result is displaying 2 or more same product with same id but different sizes in the cart before checkout.

Comment: You'll have to add an extra dimension to `$cart` and reverse engineer it at checkout. Your proposition will always overwrite product information with the same id. `cart[][$id][...]`. Otherwise, it would be easier if you consider the product sizes as 2 complete separate products and work it out from there, without the complication of an extra array dimension. Especially when users add or sub the amount of products already in the cart.

Comment: it worked i added the size of the product to the $cart and it fixed the proleme thanks!!